# Delete a row from a table thanks to a button in a UserForm using ListBox

Tags: vba, userform, listobject

I'm looking for a way to delete a row of my table at the same time as an item in my ListBox.
So far I'm only able to delete the ListBox Item but not the row in my Excel Sheet.

Here is how I initialize my ListBox :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("Tableau1")
     Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.Cells)
  End with
End Sub
```

Here is how I remove the ListBox item :

```
Private Sub CommandeButton1_Click()
  With Me.ListBox1
    For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step - 1
      If .Selected(i) Then
        .RemoveItem (i)
      End If
    Next i
 End With
End Sub
```

So far this code work, now I want to remove the value of the .Row(i) of .Range("Tableau1").

To be more clear I want to remove the row(i) of my table ("Tableau1") but not the full row of the sheet, because there is other data on the same row.

Any ideas of how to help me ?

Comment: If its actually an Excel Table then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).ListObjects("Tableau1").ListRows(i).Delete` if it just "looks" like a table then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("Tableau1").Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp`

Comment: Yes I just found the solution by myself, yours is very similar and probably work too. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandeButton1_Click()
 With Me.ListBox1
  For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step - 1
   If .Selected(i) Then
    .RemoveItem (i)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).ListObjects("Tableau1").DataBodyRange(i+1, 1).Delete
   End If
 Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to put `Exit For` after the delete. Listboxes like to auto-fill if there is only one option. You might end up deleting that if it auto-fills after you delete the second last option.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?